# Android: how do I refresh view for an updated CardView?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a RecyclerView list of CardViews created when a user enters a bunch of data with some EditTexts.  A click on a single CardView from the list loads a DetailsActivity that shows only that specific CardView to the user.  Another click on that CardView loads an EditActivity that allows the user to edit the original data they entered.

When the user saves any edited data, the EditActivity closes and the user is returned to the specific CardView.  But the CardView is not updated with the edited data.  The RecyclerView list of CardViews does update as expected because if I backspace out of the DetailsActivity and return to the MainActivity, then the CardView that was edited shows up correctly.  How do I refresh the view for the single CardView in the DetailsActivity?

```
MainActivity (the RecyclerView list)
...
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, final View view) {           
    // Create a new intent to send data from this MainActivity to the DetailsActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,CardViewDetails.class);
    // Send the position of the CardView item that was clicked on in the intent.
    intent.putExtra("position",position);
    startActivity(intent);
}

DetailsActivity (for the single CardView)
...
// Get the position of the clicked on RecyclerView list CardView from
// the MainActivity's intent bundle.
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        // get the CardView item using the int position from the
        // MainActivity's onItemClick() and the putExtra in the intent.
        position = extras.getInt("position", 0); // 0 is default value
    }

cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // pass the position variable to the start method of
        // EditActivity so get the correct data from the db can
        // be loaded onto the EditText lines, etc. of the
        // EditActivity and that can then be used to pass the
        // data back to the MainActivity.
        EditActivity.start(CardViewDetails.this,listItems.get(position));
    }
});


EditActivity (for editing the original CardView data)
...
// Launches the activity to edit an Item (CardView) that was clicked on from the
// RecyclerView list in the MainActivity file.  The intent brings the item's
// position in the RecyclerView Adapter so the correct Item is edited.
public static void start(Context context, ListItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActActivity.class);
    // From the OnItemClick method in the MainActivity the RecyclerView item
    // position from the Adapter is passed into a putExtra bundle that the
    // intent carries to this Activity.  The data is then copied in the onCreate()
    // below using getIntent().getParcelableExtra(). So this is to update an
    // existing CardView item.
    intent.putExtra(ActActivity.class.getSimpleName(),item);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickSaveEdits(View v) {
    // Update the user EditText input to the database.
    sqLiteDB.update(item);        
    // Close the EditActivity.
    finish();
    **what am I missing here to update/refresh the view for the just edited CardView that is shown in the DetailsActivity?**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter whenever you make a change to the data you're using for the RecyclerView.

For example, your `onClickSaveEdits(View v)` method would look as follows:

```
public void onClickSaveEdits(View v) {
    // Update the user EditText input to the database.
    sqLiteDB.update(item);
    adapterObjectHere.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // Close the EditActivity.
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  The RecyclerView list of CardViews is updated correctly so I assumed the adapter was updated.  The single CardView in DetailsActivity is where the view is not refreshed correctly.  Any thoughts?

Comment: When you update the data that you use to populate the RecyclerView, if you want the view itself to be updated then you have to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method. That's just the way the intended implementation is set up. The adapter doesn't update itself, and I suppose that's because of all the other things that this can be set up to handle, like animations for inserting and removing rows/cells/cards/whatever you're using and such.

Comment: The reason that you're seeing an update without actually updating the adapter is probably because when you go back to the previous activity it's reloading the RecyclerView and Adapter. Since they have new data now, they're not questioning anything and just displaying it. The best practice is to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method whenever you make a change to the data because that way everything is always up-to-date

Comment: Ok, understood.  So I added "private MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = null;" to the EditActivity and then added adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as suggested and the app crashes at first but then ultimately returns to the updated CardView, and it shows correctly with the new edits.

Comment: Logcat says: NullPointerException: Attemp to invoke virtual method '... adapter.MyRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference.

Comment: Ok, it looks like what you want to do is actually start EditActivity for a result using the, aptly named, method `startActivityForResult()` in your DetailActivity's cardView OnClickListener. That's detailed here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html.

Comment: From there, you want to return the data to the DetailActivity and do your update on the data + adapter there.

Comment: Ok so clicking Save in the EditActivity would return position in the RecyclerView list to the DetailActivity and then run notifyDataSetChanged() in DetailActivity rather than running it in EditActivity?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked something in one of your comments. The way that you have everything working should be ok. Don't bother with the `startActivityForResult()` thing. Just when you return to the DetailActivity, you should be calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` there. That should be in your `onRestart()` method.

Comment: Do you mean onResume()?

Comment: When DetailActivity becomes visible again, the system calls `onRestart()`, then `onStart()` and then `onResume()`. By calling it in `onRestart()`, my intention is to update the view before it comes on the screen. Calling it in `onResume()` might update afterwards and you might see the change, which wouldn't look nice. However, if my assumption proves wrong then call it in `onResume()`.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I will try now.

Comment: The  app crashes at first.  Logcat has the same error message: "...on a null object reference."  Then when I click "Ok" to error dialog, the CardView is returned properly with the edits showing correctly.  So I just need to remove the  null object error and then I should be good.  Any thoughts?

Comment: p.s. the app returns to the RecyclerView list after crashing.  It does not return to DetailActivity with the single CardView.  When I scroll to the CardView I just edited in the RecyclerView list and then click on it, it does bring me to the DetailActivity and the CardView shows properly with the edits.

Comment: Ok, I was able to eliminate the null object reference error by setting an adapter object in onCreate of the DetailActivity.  However, the notifyDataSetChanged() does not work to update the CardView properly.  I tried it in onRestart() and onResume().

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem. Your RecyclerView is in your MainActivity, so that's where you should be updating the adapter. It's in that Activity that the instance of the adapter that you've actually given to your RecyclerView resides and you need to use that instance to update it. Does it update if you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `onRestart()` or `onResume()` method (just down to preference now) in your MainActivity?

Comment: Ah, ok I will try that.

Comment: No luck, I added "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" in onResume().  The DetailActivity does not show the edits.  As before, when I Back button press out of the DetailActivity I return to the RecyclerView list and the CardView there shows the edits correctly.  When I click on that CardView to get to the DetailActivity to show the single CardView, the edits now show correctly.

Comment: This is the point when having full code in your question becomes really handy. Simply because I can't see further than what you've given. Are you able to update your question with the full classes?

Comment: I have run out of time tonight to solve this issue.  I will circle back tomorrow.  Thanks for your efforts to help me.

Comment: No worries at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145499/discussion-between-jake-millington-and-ajw).